# Can Spring implement JTA?

Tags: spring, jta, application-server

I read everywhere that implementations of JTA are Java EE application servers like GlassFish or Jboss which contain an EJB container. On the other hand Spring is also container so can we treat Spring like an implementation of JTA (especially that spring is built on top EJB)?

I found a [class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) from the Spring API which is an implementation of JTA but there is something like this:

> BlockquotePlatformTransactionManager implementation for JTA, delegating to a backend JTA provider. This is typically used to delegate to a J2EE server's transaction coordinator, but may also be configured with a local JTA provider which is embedded within the application.

My question is:

If we use this `JtaTransactionManager` in Spring, will JTA be managed by the EJB container inside an application server or by Spring?

Comment: Sorry there is a mistake in the title.. not JPA but JTA ...

Comment: *This is typically used to delegate to a J2EE server's transaction coordinator*. So, if the transaction coordinator is provided by the J2EE server, what do you think is implementing JTA?

Comment: Yes and I asked if Spring can implementation of JTA since it's builded on top EJB

Comment: It's not built on top of EJB. You got that wrong.

Comment: So spring cant be treated like a implementation of JTA ?

Comment: No. Spring does not provide any JTA implementation. As the documentation clearly says, it delegates to a Java EE server implementation, or to a separate local JTA provider.

Comment: Help me with that I found sth like this: "If you’re using container-managed EntityManager it automatically means that you have to use JTA EntityManager. " Spring can manage the EntityManager but then It don't have to use JTA? Am i right ?

Comment: It means that the EntityManager provided by the Java EE server only works with JTA. So if you choose to use the EntityManager provided by the Java EE server, you'll also have to use JTA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70166/discussion-between-user3528733-and-jb-nizet).